# What would be Solr schema for cassandra Map type field?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have created a table in Cassandra with following schema : -

```
create table test(a int, b map<int, int>);
insert into test(a,b) values(1, {1:100, 2:200});
```

Now I have to Sync  this table into Solr by using Import Handler method in Solr.
So what would be my schema for this field(field 'b') in Solr?

Comment: Are you using DSE, or not (I'm confused by tags)

Comment: Previously I was using DSE Solr. But I faced some issues in Analytics queries like stats with facet then I switched to Apache Solr.

Comment: And how do you want to integrate Solr with Cassandra?

Comment: By using Solr's data import handler. Which will import all the rows into cassandra.

Comment: But if you'll continuously sync all rows into Solr, then you'll get a lot of deleted documents in the index... Plus it won't handle deletes from C*

Comment: No Sir .. I don't have to delete data from cassandra.
But I am not able to create Solr schema for map type fields of cassandra table.